# dynamic rooted tree graph

Tags: data-visualization, graph-theory

Suppose I have a tree graph rooted at point P1, if I moved this point (P1) to another place in the tree, can I change the data structure by changing the points IDs so that the graph still rooted at P1 in its new place, without needing to rebuild the tree?